# SAPI does not implement phonetic alphabet selection

Tags: c#, wpf

Programando mi asistente virtual he encontrado este error:

> SAPI does not implement phonetic alphabet selection.

He revisado en foros la solución y he encontrado que tengo que añadir esta línea de código:

```
gb.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES");
```

La he añadido pero el problema continua.

**Objetivo:** Que el asistente responda tanto por medio de respuesta como con acciones.

**Pasos que llevaron a reproducir el error:** Pues no me acuerdo muy bien como ocurrió pero creo que fue por un cambio en la gui.

**Resultados actuales:** No reconoce el audio.

**Entorno:** WPF System.Speech

Gracias de antemano, este es mi código:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try{

        rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        Choices sentences = new Choices(loadSentences());

        GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
        gb.Append(sentences);
        gb.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES");

        Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
        
        rec.LoadGrammar(g);
        rec.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

        rec.SpeechRecognized += Rec_SpeechRecognized;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}


private void Rec_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (Commands c in list)
        {
            if (e.Result.Confidence > 0.6)
            {
                if (c.Command.ToString().Equals(e.Result.Text.ToString()))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(c.Command.ToString());

                    if (c.Action.Trim().Length > 0 || c.Action != null)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(c.Action.ToString());
                    }

                    if (c.Response.Trim().Length > 0)
                    {
                        nexus.SpeakAsync(c.Response.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    
}
```